# PHP mysql photo album allow one photo to be in multiple albums (database structure)

Tags: php, mysql, image, phpmyadmin

I have two tables from a mysql database with the following schema:

albums: title, date_created, date_modified, albumID (primary key)
photos: caption, image_url, date_taken, imageID (primary key)

I am creating a php/mysql powered online photo album, and I would like to allow a photo to be on multiple albums, so I didn't put albumID in photos as a foreign key.
The only way I can do this is to create a third table that relates the imageID to albumID, but so far I have failed to do this. 
What should I put on my third table that relates the imageID to albumID, and will allow users to put one photo in multiple albums.

Also, how will I query it in my php code to the mysql database to display all photos from a particular album? (i am using mysqli functions)
Any help will be very much appreciated!
thanks in advance

Code so far:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        <?php
        require_once 'config.php'; 
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
    if(isset($_POST['upload'])){
        $caption = $_POST['caption'];
        $albumID = $_POST['album'];
        $file = $_FILES ['file']['name'];
        $file_type = $_FILES ['file']['type'];
        $file_size = $_FILES ['file']['size'];
        $file_tmp = $_FILES ['file']['tmp_name'];
        $random_name = rand();

        if(empty($file)){
            echo "Please enter a file <br>";
        } else{
             move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, 'uploads/'.$random_name.'.jpg');
    $ret = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, "INSERT INTO photos (caption, image_url, date_taken, imageID)
    VALUES(?, ?, NOW()), null");
    $filename = "uploads/" . $random_name . ".jpg";
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($ret, "ss", $caption, $filename);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($ret);
    echo "Photo successfully uploaded!<br>";
    $id = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, "INSERT into album_photo (albumID, imageID) values (?, $id)");
    }
    }
    ?>
    Caption: <br>
    <input type="text" name="caption">
    <br><br>
    Select Album: <br>
    <select name="album">
    <?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM albums");
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $albumID = $row['albumID'];
        $title = $row['title'];
        echo "<option value='$albumID'>$title</option>";
    }
    ?>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    Select Photo: <br>
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload">
</form>
```

Comment: what did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

$id = $mysqli->insert_idIf you want to have a photos exist in many albums and albums to have any photos, you would need to create a many-to-many structure.  Typically you would need to create a link table, with dual primary keys.

Basically you just need a table called something like `album_photo` with two keys.  Both are primary keys in that album, which link to photo and album as foreign keys.  It could look something like this:

```
albumID (PK)    imageID (PK)
-------         -------
 1                1
 1                2
 2                1
 2                2
```

By assigning these are both primary keys,  this would behave a little different than singular primary keys.   Rather than having a single id appear only once, they are treated as a primary *pair*.  which means that a grouping can only appear once.  Also this would make sure that a combo could exist only once.

You would query it using SQL same as any other query like so (if you want to see a specific album):

```
$query = "select a.albumID, p.imageID
          from album a, photos p, album_image ai
          where a.album_ID = ai.albumID
          and p.imageID = ai.imageID
          and a.album_id = ? ";
```

and then include your variables in your statement to replace the `?`

For your insert, assuming the user is working from an existing album, the code could look something like this:

```
 $insert_photo= "insert into photos (caption, image_url, date_taken, imageID)
                 values (?, ?, ?, NULL)";

 $id = [connection variable]->insert_id

$insert_link = "insert into album_photo
                albumID, imageID values (?, ?)
                WHERE albumID = $albumID and imageID = $id";
```

where the the last ? is your current album.  Note, I only included $id in there for ease of explanation, you should also probably prepare that as well, but I won't get into that here.

EDIT:
Here's an example from your code (this should get you a little closer, but you are missing a few pieces, and make sure you get the albumID from the one the user chose first, and assuming you are getting this variable through a `mysqli_fetch` or `mysqli_fetch_array` into a `$row`):

```
$albumID = $row['albumID'];
$ret = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, "INSERT INTO photos (caption, image_url, date_taken, imageID)
VALUES(?, ?, NOW(), null");
$filename = "uploads/" . $random_name . ".jpg";
$ret->bind_param("ss", $caption, $filename);
$ret->execute();

$id = $mysqli->insert_id;
$alph = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT into album_photo (albumID, imageID) values (?, ?)  ");

//here you will need to do the rest of the binding parameters, execution, etc, just as in the first query, but off of $alph instead of $ref
$alph->bind_param("ii", $albumID, $id);
$alph->execute();
$alph->close();
$ret->close();
echo "Photo successfully uploaded!<br>";
```

Comment: thanks! how would I create this table through phpmyadmin? and would it automatically update as photos and albums are added? @nomistic

Comment: you would need to create the table separately first, and then when you do an insert, you would need to make sure (in your php file)  that the items were entered into `album` and `photos` *first* before being inserted into `album_photo`.  NOTE:  make sure you use `mysqli_insert_id` (if that is the approach you are taking) to make sure that the id for the item being entered is being correctly entered into `album_photo`

Comment: I have created the table separately, my code for inserting album and photos can be found in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29220266/uploading-pictures-picture-information-from-php-form-to-mysql-database?noredirect=1#comment46654544_29220266 , how do i use mysqli_insert_id to enter the information to album_photo?

Comment: I just added some edits.   This should get you started.   Please mark this if it answers your question.  (From what you wrote in that other example, I see you have a clear grasp of prepared statements.   Basically put the insert id after the first query and execution, then run the second one.)

Comment: I have added code, i made changes based on your suggestions however I think i did something wrong with $id and also maybe I didn't put it in the code in the right place? should i put it before or after the caption and select album parts of the form?@nomistic

Comment: I don't see a `mysqli_insert_id` in your code?  It's crucial to make this work.  The `$id` I demonstrated is just a placeholder to represent it.

Comment: Note, the example I provided is pretty close to literal.  In other words, items just appear in that order to work (you can modify for your own code)

Comment: mysqli insert id is deprecatedv @nomistic

Comment: actually it isn't;  it's just the procedural approach.   http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php  (are you thinking of `mysql_insert_id`?)  Anyway you can use this if you choose. `$mysqli->insert_id` same thing, but you still need it.  You can do it like this `$id = $mysqli->insert_id`  I'll edit the above to be OO style.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73674/discussion-between-mar-and-nomistic).

Comment: sorry, I'm at work, so I don't really have time, but I'll try an edit with your code above to show you

Comment: sorry! thank you very much for your help! @nomistic i really appreciate it

Comment: where did you edit the code? @nomistic in my post of the question ?

Comment: I just added it at the bottom

Comment: is this correct for binding the parameters and execution? mysqli_stmt_bind_param($alph, $albumID, $imageID);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($alph);    @nomistic i apologize for all the questions i am very new to this and it's quite confusing to me

Comment: see me over in the chat window

Comment: check the chat for an answer to your question

Comment: there was an error in the insert code into photos;  edited and fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using an ORM like Doctrine or Eloquent? You can use those to implement a `many-to-many` relationship (which is the technical name for what you're trying to do here).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/474401/582278) is a good summary for how to implement a simple many-to-many relationship in SQL.